# iOS: retrieving selection state from button created in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UIButton` on a custom `UITableViewCell` (to which cells are added dynamically), which is defined on a different class than the `MainViewController`, the `CustomCell` class. I need a method in the `MainViewController` to return an array with if the `UIButton`s are selected or not. This array should have in the n-th index the information about the n-th cell.
What I have written is:

`CustomCell.h`:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tickButton;
```

`CustomCell.m`:

```
- (IBAction)tick:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

`MainViewController.m`:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) returnTickArray{
    NSMutableArray *tickArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<n; i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0];
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.itemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([cell.tickButton isSelected]){
            a=[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        }
        else {
            a=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        };
        [tickArray addObject:a];
    }

    return tickArray;

}
```

I have also tried instead of using the button selected state to create a public `NSNumber` property and having the `UIButton` make it alternate between `1` and `0`, and then "asking for it" on `MainViewController`, but it also hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]; that is always 1 row. you should replace it with 'i' as you are using in the loop.